# Hibernate 6 persist entity with field of marker interface type in JSON format

Tags: json, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to use hibernate 6 `SqlTypes` new feature which should give us possibility to use serialize object fields to and from JSON seemlessly.

So I decided to try it out and wrote this entity:

```
@Entity(name = DBConstants.Tables.HISTORY)
@Table(name = DBConstants.Tables.HISTORY, schema = DBConstants.SCHEMA)
class HistoryEntryEntity(
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    @Column(name = "data")
    var data: MarkerInterface,
) : Identifiable<Long>()
```

Where MarkerInterface is an interface which is implemented by number of kotlin `data classes`. The insert of this has a result of empty JSON in column `data` in DB.

So here is my question: is there any possibility I can instruct hibernate to preserve type information so I can use it to serialize and deserialize entity in such a situation?